# How to Authenticate SharePoint 2016 on premises using GMAIL

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, saml

in short my client employees want to access the application using their Gmail account rather using username and password in NTLM default identity provider.is there a way to implement a such requirement. i see SharePoint supports SAML 1.0 authentication  protocol and google uses 2.0.